# What to do with exceptions in java?

Tags: java, exception

I am beginner in Java programming. But i have code below

```
  Socket socket = serverSocketObj.accept();
  BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
  try {
    writer.writeLine();
  } catch(IOException e ) {
    //write to logger here
  } finally {
    writer.close(); // this throws IOExceptioin too. What to do with it
    // Possible memmory leak?
    socket.close();
  }
```

When i try to close `writer` i should handle another Exception. But i don't know what to do with it. Is this Exception impossible in my case? Can i just ignore it?

Comment: i'd put another try catch inside finally.

Comment: yes, add another catch after you null-check it (for the obvious `NullPointerException`)

Comment: @peter.petrov Anyway i should write try-catch block in finally to e.printStackTrace()

Comment: This is akin to the old "double-fault" with _old_ x86 systems.  Older CPUs had "exception" handling built-in, but if they tried and failed to handle a hardware exception they'd double-fault and restart the entire system.  Since the 80286 the system won't shut down unless a triple-fault occurred - designing your software similarly (catch and gracefully shut down after a double-fault) is considered best practice.  The idea is, if `close` throws a fault after a `read` or `write` failure, as a programmer you don't know what else to do but shut your own system down and log what happened as you can.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know what to do with them, just catch them and log them.
The simplest way of logging them is `e.printStackTrace()` This way,
at least you'll always see there's a problem if an exception occurs.

Another approach is to just re-throw the exceptions to upper-level code.
E.g. if your method (in which your sample code is) declares to throw `IOException`,
then there's nothing you should worry about. Let upper-level code worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the writer and socket are not null.

```
 Socket socket = serverSocketObj.accept();
  BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
try {     
    writer.writeLine();
  } catch(IOException e ) {
    //write to logger here
  } finally {
    if(writer != null)
    writer.close(); // this throws IOExceptioin too. What to do with it
    // Possible memmory leak?
    if(socket != null)
    socket.close();
  }
```

Comment: Neither writer, nor socket can be null there. The OP's problem are the compiler errors of not handling the exceptions.

Comment: edited the answer...if try is placed above then it might be possible

Comment: Whether or not writer or socket is null, if they _aren't_ null the `close` calls can still throw a checked exception which is not handled, and will be a compiler error.

Comment: @AakashGoyal The way you have it, with the socket and writer declared inside the try, they are not visible to the finally block.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, to make the compiler happy you must catch the potential IOExceptions from the `close` statements (assuming you don't add IOException to your method's `throws` clause).  (Thank you Mr Goodenough!)

But there's nothing you can really do to "handle" the exception once you have it, other than to log it.

(I'm thinking that the new "[try with resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)" structure in Java may handle this all a bit cleaner.)

Comment: One word: "rethrow" :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Then there'd be no point in catching the exception.

Comment: Catching is forced upon your throat by the compiler. We wrap and rethrow. Advanced Java users don't wrap, but rethrow sneakily :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - But there's no point in throwing an exception for a "secondary" error such as one in a close inside a catch or finally, following an exception with the Socket/Reader.  It's the primary error, if any, that needs to be reported.  Throwing an exception due to the secondary error merely confuses things more and hides the real error.

Comment: Supposedly Java 7's try-with-resources captures the best practice here, and it throws both from the main block and from the finally. Of course, the one from try should dominate, but if `try` completes normally and `finally` receives an exception, it should rethrow.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Right, but if the try fails then that needs to "win".  The "best" non-with-resources implementation is to move the Reader `close` out of `finally` into `catch`, surround it with another try, and essentially ignore any errors from that.  Then use a flag to condition executing the `close` outside the original try/catch block (but, alas, inside another one), for the error-free case.  But that all gets awfully messy.

Comment: I did say "the one from try should dominate"---but yes, it's awfully messy, which is why try-with-resources is a lifesaver. No application I have seen was actually implementing it all the way.